# OS X Mavericks: Screenshot of window containing layer-backed view displays horribly rendered text. Advice?

Tags: objective-c, screenshot, calayer, osx-mavericks, antialiasing

I'm trying to design the Preferences window for my app, so I've been taking screenshots to use in Photoshop and Omnigraffle (I tried laying stuff out in Interface Builder, but it's one of the worst visual layout tools I've ever used [no zooming?]. I honestly can't believe it's a product of the folks at Cupertino, but I digress.).

Anyway, when I take a fullscreen screenshot via <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> or a single window screenshot via <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, the rendering of text in layer-backed views is super ugly — and not in the usual CALayer "U can haz no sub-pixelz" way either. When taking a fullscreen shot, it doesn't change the way the text is actually rendered; it just renders poorly in the screenshot. When taking the window-only screenshot, however, it actually changes the view's rendered text, and it's pretty bad.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: Screenshot of Preferences window]

You'll notice that the text displayed in my custom "Indicator Style" control and several of the other labels aren't ugly because in trying to figure out what's up with the rendering, I gave them opaque backgrounds using the "Window Background" color.

If anyone would be willing to help a brotha out, it'd be much appreciated.

P.S. Don't judge any window styling. It's still a work-in-progress. :-)

**Edit:** I just took a screenshot of Xcode's own Preferences window, and what do you know?! Even Apple's views are suffering from what I've described (see screenshot below). So, does this mean that this is a Mavericks bug we're dealing with? Anyone have some top secret inside info? I wonder if this is related to Quartz in some way because ever since upgrading to Mavericks, my favorite screensaver (Arabesque) is totally screwed up, too. Oh, well …

[image: Xcode Preferences window displaying heavy text]

Comment: well.. it isn't completely apparent to me the evil of which you speak.. perhaps you could have a portion of  the screenshot blown up instead of reduced.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I haven't altered the size of the screenshots in any way. In my last screenshot, I _did_ add some green arrows using Preview. However, the actual rendered text (in the window) becomes heavy when taking a single-window screenshot, so it's not an issue of image resizing. Thanks for the input though. (My questions must be really boring because I'm the tumbleweed king on SO).

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I re-read your comment and I think I misunderstood you the first time. My bad. If you right-click on the image, and open it in a new tab, you'll see the shot at actual size.

Comment: that kind of does look like you you can haz no sub-pixels to me... with anti aliasing off.